# to get ip address from contacts or inbox in gmail

Tags: google-apps-script

Google apps script.

How can i get ip of the email sender or from contacts in gmail contacts.
I can import contact details from a group or mail threads from inbox. 
can i get the ip address of sender by apps script code sample?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You simply cannot do that... moreover, the IP adress of a contact is something that doesn't exist in real world, the IP a user is using depends on where the contact is doesn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

This gets the originating IP from the first email thread in you inbox:

```
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // get first thread in inbox
  var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // get first message
  var rawMessage = message.getRawContent();
  var lines = rawMessage.split('\n');
  for each(line in lines){
    if(line.substring(0,'X-Originating-IP'.length)=='X-Originating-IP'){
      Logger.log(line);
    }
  }
```