# What server would emails sent by my Google Apps Script applications come from?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, server, ip-address

I have built numerous small applications in GAS, some of which send emails. I need to know what IP address these emails will register as being sent from.

Comment: There is no list of IPs for Google's mail infra.

Answer (score 1):

> Here's a solution by [@Serge insas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1368381/serge-insas) on [how to get your ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21883442/10521959).

**In summary:** access the raw content of a message using `message.getRawContent()` and filter for `X-Originating-IP`

Answer (score 0):

They come from your google/gmail address.